# Example of non-vanishing of first cohomology of a torsion coherent sheaf on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, algebraic-curves, sheaf-cohomology

By a curve we mean a projective scheme of pure dimension one. Can some one give an example of a curve $C$ and a torsion coherent sheaf on $C$ such that its first cohomology group does not vanish?

**EDIT** By torsion sheaf I mean the stalk at the generic point is torsion. The curve is not necessarily reduced.

Comment: That doesn't exist. A torsion coherent sheaf has finite support, all its $H^i$ vanish for $i>0$.

Comment: Depends on what do you mean by a torsion sheaf. As abx noted, for reduced curves it is impossible. You can take (say) $C:=$Proj $k[x,y,z]/z^2$ and any coherent sheaf $F$ on $C_{red}$ with $H^1(C_{red},F)\ne0$. Since $F$ can be seen as a coherent sheaf over $C$ and it has torsion at a generic point, you get a desired example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just making the above comment an answer.

Take $C:=\text{Proj}\ \big(k[x,y,z]/z^2\big)$. Then $C_{\text{red}}={\mathbb P}_k^1$ and the coherent sheaf $F:={\mathcal O}_{{\mathbb P}_k^1}(-2)$ over ${\mathbb P}_k^1$ is known to satisfy
$H^1\big({\mathbb P}_k^1,{\mathcal O}_{{\mathbb P}_k^1}(-2)\big)=k$. Since $F$ can be seen as a coherent sheaf over $C$, and it has torsion at a generic point that comes from the nilpotent $z/x$, you get a desired example due to $H^1(C,F)=H^1(C_{red},F)=k\ne0$.